# Is there a design pattern in the building of website validation with JS and PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, validation

For example, I want avoid errors if someone disables Javascript... I think my JS validation must be called by my PHP code...

I'd like know about design patterns or anti-design patterns.

I should clarify that I must use JS in my project and not tools like jQuery or Dojo

Comment: always do both : client validation (js) and server validation (php)

Comment: I don't understand why you can't use JQuery, today, no one codes pure JS anymore, it is bulky in terms of quantities of code and doesn't enforce perfect cross-browser compatibility. If this is a school project, you might want to refer your teacher to some technical reading on validation, half if not more of the developper community will be happy to tell him he's wrong!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is more often how to keep both validation identical on the client using JS and on the server using PHP. What i often do is i create my validation on the server only using PHP and i send the content through AJAX using jquery.

The server sees that request as an ajax request because i pass it a content-type and then it doesn't process anything, just validates and returns a JSON response saying everything is ok, or it sends back the error messages that jquery will have to show to the user.

Like you asked, it's only a design pattern, a way of doing. Implementing it is another story, there are tons of ways to do it.

Good luck

Comment: Thanks, but my goal is write JS

Answer (score 1):

There are several jQuery plugins that have validation, and some tie it to classes on the fields. This way, you can keep your javascript and your PHP separate.

The important thing is that there needs to be two sides to validation: server-side *and* client-side. So while you can validate with JavaScript, mainly for usability reasons, you need validation on the server side as well, for reliability reasons. This way if someone has turned validation off, you can still prevent errors that un-validated data may cause.

Comment: Thanks, but my goal is write JS and don't use frameworks like jQuery

Comment: I assume you are talking about input validation. It must be done on the server for security reasons. Anyone can forge a post. Client side validation is for user benefit, to catch errors before the form is submitted allowing the user to correct them without needing to reload the form.

Comment: I do not understand why your goal is to write JS and not use something like jQuery, which does a wonderful job at detecting the browser and taking care of the numerous slight differences between browsers and versions for you. Also, you can never rely on JS alone simply for accessibility reasons. A braille or audio browser for the blind is unlikely to even have JS available.